SELinux denies samba share
Trying to configure samba to share my drives (locally to virtual machines). Using Fedora.
The shares work with sudo setenforce 0, so it's a SELinux issue
Here are my SELinux rules.
sudo semanage fcontext -l | grep samba
/home/hanuman(/.*)?                                all files          system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 
/run/media/hanuman(/.*)?                           all files          system_u:object_r:samba_share_t:s0 

Here's the log
type=AVC msg=audit(1718035536.971:480): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=7754 comm="smbd[192.168.1." path=2F72756E2F6D656469612F68616E756D616E2F53746F726167652D6E7466732F4D6F73742042656175746966756C204368696E65736520536F6E6720596F752077696C6C20457665722048656172203230313020323031352E6D7033 dev="sda1" ino=228609 scontext=system_u:system_r:smbd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

What am I missing?
I'm noting smbd_t vs samba_share_t, what is that difference about?
audit2allow -w -a suggests setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw 1 which, although would work, is not the best solution.

The log speaks for itself: you need an SELINUX rule allowing the calls from smb_t to fusefs_t contexts.
As, you may find that building your own SELinux policy from scratch may not be straightforward, you should better consider using one of the available booleans semanage boolean -l. Even if it is not "tailor made", it has the merit of existing, and will save you a lot of time.
Moreover, SELINUX is just one layer of security amongst others, so i don't understand why you consider not to be an acceptable solution...
As explained in this article (https://selinuxproject.org/page/SambaRecipes), you may find various SMB related booleans. Just choose the one that best fit your need:

setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro=1
setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw=1
setsebool -P allow_smbd_anon_write=1
setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs=1
setsebool -P use_samba_home_dirs=1


Ya after setting SELinux flags rendered the system unbootable, I figured out I'm best to simply use samba_export_all_rw. Wanted to learn the "right" way to do it though as a first-time SELinux user (and just realized that the Arch-based install I used for a few years have neither SELinux nor AppArmor)

yes. Moreover, if you did not achieve to recover your system to a bootable state, just ask me and i may help you in this too.

I asked Chat GPT how to fix its own mess. I told me to boot, edit the boot args, add "single" and boot. Then remove the custom rule, then call restorecon again. It's back to normal.

Chat GPT answered:
sudo restorecon -Rv /home/hanuman
sudo restorecon -Rv /run/media/hanuman

That actually solved the issue; retagging the entire drives.
First time I get a useful answer from that thing.
EDIT: Actually it nuked my system and I couldn't log in anymore. Restorecon does seem to be necessary for file shares BUT doing that on your entire home directly breaks your system!
So that's not the solution.
